Help identify sci-fi horror movie with killer cyborg experiment
I remember only having a glimpse of this movie as a child. This was around 1996ish. But I can not get it out of my head and I'm dying to know what it was.
Movie looked like it was from the late 80s to early 90s. From what I remember there's a group of people trapped in a facility and there are these bloody human robot creatures trying to kill them. I remember one in particular was played by a black man and his mechanical neck extended about a foot higher that it should. Not sure if the ppl escaped or they found a way to shut down those cyborg things. 
Sorry it's so vague. Any help would be appreciated.

It's possible you're after Return of the Living Dead III from 1993. If you are, please tell me and I'll mark the question as duplicate.

BTW, what's 'scoff'? Is it 'sci-fi' autocorrected?

I believe this was the movie. I have to watch it now to make sure haha.  I can't believe my parents let me watch this stuff haha. Thank you! And yes it was suppose to be "sci-fi". Darn that autocorrect!

I just checked my copy of Return of the Living Dead III. The black guy's head does not extend. It's bolted down, plus they are zombies not really cyborgs. So, this makes me think it might be a different movie. I've posted an answer of what I think it might be.

@druciferre Memory's a bit vague, but I'm pretty sure there's a zombie with a really long neck there.

There is a zombie in a cage which is just a head on a spine. It's only shown for a few seconds and it's not a black guy. Other than that I didn't see any zombies with long necks.

In ROTLD3, Julie does that to Santos, the lead (caucasian) dirt-bag.  He becomes a zombie with his head at the end of his spine pulled a good ways out from his body.  Here's a still: http://i.ytimg.com/vi/V-tFfvteKZ8/hqdefault.jpg.  The govt. was trying to weaponize them.  They look like cyborgs because the govt. had them in exoskeletons meant to immobilize them when they were not in battle.

Your description brings to mind the movie Virus (1999) starring Jamie Lee Curtis. The crew is trapped on a large ship and a computer virus infects the ship and starts making human cyborgs and kills most of the crew. There is a black man who becomes a cyborg, but I cannot recall for sure if his neck ever extends. Here are some screenshots of the movie. 


Could it be the movie Class of 1999?



The end scenes occur inside the High School buildings, where three cybernetic teachers try to kill the most trouble some students.

Broder Its The Movie, Return of the Living Dead 3 i just feel so awesome that i found the movie name after decade,  When I was Kid, Me And My Whole Family Saw that movie on tv from since we all were guessing that we will sure again watch this movie again, but we never get the chance ... yuhoooooooo!!!!!

What are you trying to say here? Is this supposed to be an answer? Who is Broder? And Walt found it. And why all the capital letters?  Never "hot" the chance? So many problems with this...
